# Parametric family for power model

Tags: distributions

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\bw}{\mathbf{w}}\newcommand{\bmu}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}$I'm working with a likelihood that has a parametric form to weight observations under a power function and I'm not sure if there is an existing distributional family that captures this behavior. Let $\bw \in \R_{>0}^n$, $c \in \R$, and define $\bw^c$ to be the element-wise power operator. Is there a parametric family that takes the form $$p(\bw | c, \bmu, \bA) \propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\bw^{c/2} - \bmu)^T\bA(\bw^{c/2} - \bmu)),$$ for $\bmu \in \R^n$, $\bA \succ 0$? For a fixed value of $c=2$ it's not hard to see the multivariate normal, however intuition is a bit lost on me, given the constraint of $w_i > 0$ (unless this is more reflective of some folded or half MVN). But when $c$ is an explicit parameter, I'm unsure if this has been described in previous literature.

Comment: You still need to negate it!  Assuming that, your model would be a truncated version of the MVN with a common Box-Cox transformation.  For interpretability, I I think most people would replace $\mu$ by $\mu^{c/2}$ in the parameterization.

Comment: You might be interested in a multivariate version of the so-called *generalized error distribution*, although that requires you to change to $ (w-\mu)^{c/2}$, which looks more natural. A paper is at https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2265027